# Deserialize a multidimensional Json response

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm currently stuck on JSON deserialization.

Here is two type of JSON, I can receive :

```
{

"code": 0,
"response": {
    "isFollowing": false,
    "isFollowedBy": false,
    "connections": {
        "google": {
            "url": "",
            "id": "c35f4e",
            "name": "jean"
        },
        "facebook": {
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
            "id": "1000064139",
            "name": "jean mic"
        }
    },
    "isPrimary": true,
    "id": "780",
    "location": "",
    "isPrivate": false,
    "joinedAt": "2013-10-18T16:04:09",
    "username": "jeandavid",
    "numLikesReceived": 0,
    "about": "",
    "name": "jean",
    "url": "",
    "profileUrl": "",
    "reputation": ,
    "avatar": {
        "small": {
            "permalink": "https://picture.jpg",
            "cache": "https://picture.jpg"
        },
        "isCustom": false,
        "permalink": "https://picture.jpg",
        "cache": "/noavatar9.png",
        "large": {
            "permalink": "w",
            "cache": "https://picture.jpg"
        }
    },
    "isAnonymous": false
}

}
```

And this one :

```
{

"response": [
    {
        "uid": 2017156,
        "first_name": "David",
        "last_name": "Jean",
        "sex": 1,
        "nickname": "",
        "bdate": "12.12.1990",
        "photo_medium": "img.jpg"
    }
]

}
```

At beginning, I use :

```
Dictionary<string, string> deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

But it works only with unidimensional Json data.

So after looking on Google, I tried to use :

```
JArray jArr = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
foreach (var item in jArr)
{
Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

But I receive this exception :

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.

For the first JSON data I would like to get the Google and Facebook data and also the username, the reputation, the avatar, the id of the user, ...

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Did you mean you get 2 types of json from the same source and you need a generic way to extract data out of it?

Comment: Anybody can help me please?